# How to estimate Bigquery data size for Dataproc job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

In GCP we will be using Dataproc to process data present in the BigQuery tables.

We wanted to estimate the Dataproc cluster size based on the data size present in BigQuery.

In BigQuery UI console, we see multiple metadata for a table out of which the below two are the ones which we are focusing on:

```
TOTAL_LOGICAL_BYTES
TOTAL_PHYSICAL_BYTES
```

Going by what is mentioned here :
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage?authuser=1

my understanding is that we need to consider the physical bytes as that is what will be processed by Pyspark in the dataproc job?

Comment: I believe it's whatever the dataset billing model is assigned for that dataset. For more details visit this link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets-intro?authuser=1#dataset_storage_billing_models also another note that you can change the logical bytes into physical as mentioned in the link (Also another note that you cannot revert it back once you decided to change it to Physical. )

Comment: This is more about configuring and optimising the pyspark jobs based on input data size, rather than billing.